# How to enforce constructor injection with checkstyle or PMD?

Tags: java, annotations, guice, checkstyle, pmd

I'd like to enforce constructor injection in a GWT project with uses the Guice annotation `com.google.inject.Inject` which is either place on fields for field injection and on constructors for constructor injection.

The project already uses checkstyle and PMD.

Afaik I could simply enforce constructor injection by disallowing the annotation on fields, however I find no checkstyle module or PMD rule to do this. I'm sure that I'm missing something because it seems like an everyday task for a static code analysis tool.

Comment: This is an easy task for PMD. Even though there is no out-of-the-box rule for this, PMD allows easy extension and customization. You can create your own rules (https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.31.0/pmd_userdocs_extending_writing_rules_intro.html), and specially for this case, an XPath rule should be trivial (https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.31.0/pmd_userdocs_extending_writing_xpath_rules.html)

Comment: I've suggested this before. It might be a good idea to create a separate repo for user-contributed rules that other users can refer to and use which would be apart from the core PMD rules. This is different from experimental rules. Similar to Checkstyle's sevntu checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a good candidate for Checkstyle's [MatchXpath](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_coding.html#MatchXpath) check. You could add two modules to your configuration like so:

```
<module name="MatchXpath">
  <property name="query" value="//VARIABLE_DEF/MODIFIERS/ANNOTATION/IDENT[@text='Inject']"/>
  <message key="matchxpath.match"
                     value="Inject annotation only allowed on constructors."/>
</module>

<module name="MatchXpath">
  <property name="query" value="//METHOD_DEF/MODIFIERS/ANNOTATION[./IDENT[@text='Inject']]"/>
  <message key="matchxpath.match"
                     value="Inject annotation only allowed on constructors."/>
</module>
```

Example java file:

```java
public class Communication {
    @Inject @Named("SMSComms")
    CommunicationMode smsComms;

    @Inject
    public void setEmailCommunicator(@Named("EmailComms") CommunicationMode emailComms) {
        this.emailComms = emailComms;
    }

    @Inject
    public Communication(@Named("IMComms") CommunicationMode imComms) {
        this.imComms = imComms;
    }
}
```

Result:

```sh
➜  src java -jar checkstyle-8.40-all.jar -c config.xml Communication.java
Starting audit...
[ERROR] src/Communication.java:2:6: Inject annotation only allowed on constructors. [MatchXpath]
[ERROR] src/Communication.java:5:5: Inject annotation only allowed on constructors. [MatchXpath]
Audit done.
Checkstyle ends with 2 errors.
```